# How to draw a star chart?

Tags: astronomy, stars

How does one draw a star chart like [this](http://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/publications/starcharts/03.12starchart.jpg)?

I have:

1. a star database with coordinates (right ascension - RA, declination - DEC),
2. observer coordinates (latitude, longitude) and
3. time of observation.

I need a formula which considers these parameters (mapping star coordinates to a 2D image). e.g.

starX = (90-abs(DEC)) * cos(RA)

starY = (90-abs(DEC)) * sin(RA)

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with this page from the [US Naval Observatory](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/Alt_Az.php).  The formulas are pretty simple and give you azimuth and elevation.  The star chart you linked is basically a polar plot then, with the azimuth being the angle of the plot and (90 - elevation) being the radius.